# How to make basic POST request to google sheets REST API?

Tags: android, android-volley, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to append value in google spreadsheets using POST request (append).

While making GET request based on JsonObjectRequest using API key (generated on google cloud) I'm getting no errors and everything work fine. But when I try to use similar POST request (inserting values to store in spreadsheet in the requestBody), android studio throws me an error:

```
E/Volley: [165] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4[...rest of my url...]
D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
```

Is it because I've made the request body incorrectly or I've failed to authenticate my request? I presume my authentication is ok, because the GET request gets no errors. Can you help me and say what is wrong in my request?

I'm quite new to android programming and using REST APIs, so maybe there is something I don't understand. My code is mostly based on what I've found on stack-overflow:

```
   public void getSheetInfo(View view) throws JSONException {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    final String url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<HereIsMySpreadsheetID>/values/Sheet1!A1:append?key=<HereIsMyAPIKey>";

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    Object a1 = "TEST appended Row 1 Column A";
    jsonBody.put("values", a1);
    final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: The POST request in REST api is used to create new resource(new spreadsheet in your case).To update the existing spreadsheet you have to make the PUT request to the server. Change `Request.Method.POST` to `Request.Method.PUT`

Comment: based on what google says here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append
append method is made by POST request since it writes to next (presumably empty) cell.